# ¿Como obtener todos los valores de un objeto?

Tags: javascript

```
const obj = [{
nombre: "Nombre...",
apellidos: "Coo..",
edad: 22
}]

console.log(Object.values(obj))

let nuw_obj = obj.map(function(p){
 console.log(p.nombre)
})
```

Quiero acceder a todos los valores y no por sus keys

```
//Nombre...Coo..22
```

Comment: `for (var i in obj[0]){
 console.log(obj[0][i]);
}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes utilizar [Object.values(obj)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/values) recorriendo cada ítem de tu array de objetos.

```js
const personas = [
  { nombre: 'p1', apellidos: 'sona 1', edad: 1 },
  { nombre: 'p2', apellidos: 'sona 2', edad: 2 },
  { nombre: 'p3', apellidos: 'sona 3', edad: 2 }
];

personas.forEach(persona => console.log(Object.values(persona)));
```

Answer (score 4):

Podrías hacerlo de estas dos maneras:

**1. Utilizando solo javaScript**

```js
const obj = [{
nombre: "Nombre...",
apellidos: "Coo..",
edad: 22
}];

let nuw_obj = obj.map(function(p){
    for (var item in p) {
        console.log(p[item])
    }
})
```

**2. Utilizando jQuery**

```js
const obj = [{
nombre: "Nombre...",
apellidos: "Coo..",
edad: 22
}];

let nuw_obj = obj.map(function(p){
    $.each(p, function(index, dato){
        console.log(dato)
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Por qué no pruebas imprimiendo el objeto como tal de esta manera:

```js
const obj = [{
  nombre: "Nombre...",
  apellidos: "Coo..",
  edad: 22
}];

console.log(Object.values(obj));

let nuw_obj = obj.map(function(p) {
  console.log(p);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes intentar lo siguiente:

```js
var foo = [{
nombre: "Nombre...",
apellidos: "Coo..",
edad: 22
},
{
nombre: "Nombre2...",
apellidos: "Coo2..",
edad: 33
}];

for (var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
 for (var key in foo[i]) {
  console.log( key + ": " + foo[0][key]);
 }
}
```

Con esto recorres el objeto sacado sus valores ademas de que también puedes ver que `key` tienen asignados(para futuros procesos).

Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 2):

**6 formas distintas:**

```js
const obj = {comunnity: 'Stack Overflow', from: 'Chile'};

/* Forma 1 */
for(var i in obj) console.log(obj[i])
/* Forma 2 */
for(var e of Object.values(obj)) console.log(e);
/* Forma 3 */
console.log(Object.values(new Array(obj)[new Array(obj).length-1]));
/* Forma 4 */
new Array(obj).map(e => {
 console.log(e);
});
/* Forma 5 */
new Array(obj).filter(e => {
  console.log(e);
});
/* Forma 6 */
Object.keys(obj).forEach(e => {console.log(obj[e])});
```